# One to five star rating where 1 star = 0%

Tags: ruby, math

Silly question, but I need a simple way of computing a score where:

```
1 star = 0%
2 star = 25%
3 star = 50%
4 star = 75%
5 star = 100%
```

The tricky part comes for me when I have an average score which then becomes a float like 1.2 or 2.3, etc... Preferably in Ruby, but basic math formula will do!

Thanks!

Comment: What about `to_i`?  What are you trying to do?

Comment: So what is it that you expect with, for example, a 63% score? You should just round the number up or down, depending on your preferences. (I'd suggest using half-stars and fractions of stars, though, a la Netflix or Amazon if it's for a rating system.)

Comment: Well, the issue is averaging ratings for all product reviews, etc.. You end up with a float.. and I need a formula to convert that to a percentage scale with 1 being 0% and 5 being 100%

Comment: `(star_score - 1) * 25`?

Comment: Are you trying to calculate stars from score or the other way around?

Comment: No, I'm holding a score in a DB, like 1, 2, 3, 4, 5... based on the number of stars selected.. Then when I average two scores together I end up with 1.5 or something.. Then I need a percentage.. So basically  Matt has answered my really dumb question.. I will just do ((score-1)/4)*100

Comment: Sawa, don't be a douche bag. LOL

Comment: I have voted to close it, btw. So if you want to be helpful. Vote too, don't downvote me or belittle me. Thanks SO community.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a simple mathematical formula which describes your output for integer-valued inputs (number of stars). If you meant that the input is percentages and the output is a star rating, just invert the function.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that's all I needed.. Just something simple.. It's been a while since I took a math class... DOH. Will accept when I can.

Comment: All I did was play around with Google's built-in calculator for 3 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

For percentage to stars, you want something like:

```
numStars = int (percentVal / 25) + 1
```

That will assign 1 for `0 thru 24.999..`, 2 for `25 thru 49.999..` and so on up to 5 for `100`.

In other words, it uses truncation, effectively imposing a *hard* threshold: you _have to reach 50 to get three stars.

If you want to go the other way (from stars to percentage), the calculation is:

```
percentVal = numStars * 25 + 1
```

and you can, if desired,  round your averaged `numStars` value however you see fit before the calculation.